# automount removable media using udev in NixOS

Tags: udev, automounting, nixos

I want an udevrule to automatically mount usb sticks or sd-cards, if plugged into a terminal-computer. The way I tried to achieve this was adding an udevrule and make use of pmount's ability to mount devices as non root user.

The followig extraRule is defined in my `configuration.nix`:

```
services.udev.extraRules = ''
         ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="${pkgs.bash}/bin/bash -c '${pkgs.pmount}/bin/pmount --sync --umask 000 %N &>> /tmp/udev-pmount.log'"
 '';
```

The error output in `/tmp/udev-pmount.log` is:

```
mount: /media/sdd2: permission denied.
```

The /media folder has 777 permissions and is empty

Executing the same command with `sudo` manually works by the way.

I have no idea how to get pmount and udev working correctly in NixOS to achieve that task.

Just for reference I add a link to [automount.nix](https://github.com/fiksn/nix/blob/cf891c32f46402c2e99914f9f701a158d203a4e8/nixos/profiles/automount.nix), where similar things should be achieved. But it does not work because `KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]"` does not match anything.

Answer (score 2):

Even though, the following solution is not a solution where `pmount` is involved, the following is the simple most udev automounting rule, that was able to automount storage in a reproducible manner.

```
services.udev.extraRules = ''
     ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_USAGE}=="filesystem", RUN{program}+="${pkgs.systemd}/bin/systemd-mount --no-block --automount=yes --collect $devnode /media"       
'';
```

The solution has been found [within the arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Udev#Mounting_drives_in_rules), which is mentioned in various answers concerning automount using `udev`.